# How to stop function doajax_red and doajax_blue , When check radio button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How to stop function `doajax_red` and `doajax_blue` , When checked radio button ?

First , when you load page `index.php` and then press `red button` you will see `loading img`

and the checked `radio button BLUE`  and the checked `radio button RED` again

loading img still show ,
.

.

How to stop function `doajax_red` when checked radio button `BLUE`

and stop function `doajax_blue` when checked radio button `RED`

http://jsfiddle.net/xq0kt3kk/4/

index.php

.
.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" id="buy_out_form-id" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
<script>
// script for hide.show element base on radio button //
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".color").click(function(){
       if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
           $("#red").show();
           $("#blue").hide();  

       }
       if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
           $("#blue").show();
           $("#red").hide();  
       }
   });
});
</script>
<input onchange="javascript:e.preventDefault();this.form.submit();" class="color" type="radio" name="rdSpace" value="red" checked="">RED
<br>
<input onchange="javascript:e.preventDefault();this.form.submit();" class="color" type="radio" name="rdSpace" value="blue">BLUE
<br>
<span id="red">
<input type="button" id="button_red" value="RED" onclick="doajax_red()"/>
<span id="loading_red" style="display: none; width: 100px; text-align: center; "><img src="http://www.demo.mangaldeep.co.in/image/loading.gif"/></span>
</span>
<span id="blue" style="display: none;">
<input type="button" id="button_blue" value="BLUE" onclick="doajax_blue()"/>
<span id="loading_blue" style="display: none; width: 100px; text-align: center; "><img src="http://www.demo.mangaldeep.co.in/image/loading.gif"/></span>
</span>
</form>



<script>
function doajax_red() {
    $("#button_red").attr("disabled", true);
    $('#myplace_red').hide();
    $("#loading_red").show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'test_red.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#buy_out_form-id').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#loading_red").hide();
                    $("#button_red").attr("disabled", false);
                    $('#myplace_red').show();
                    $('#myplace_red').html(data);
                }
            }
        )
    }, 10000);
}
</script>




<script>
function doajax_blue() {
    $("#button_blue").attr("disabled", true);
    $('#myplace_blue').hide();
    $("#loading_blue").show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'test_blue.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#buy_out_form-id').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#loading_blue").hide();
                    $("#button_blue").attr("disabled", false);
                    $('#myplace_blue').show();
                    $('#myplace_blue').html(data);
                }
            }
        )
    }, 10000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: clearTimeout is your friend

Comment: You should disabled both button on click and enable on success

Answer (score 0):

You should create two variables for the `setTimeout`s, like `RED_TIMEOUT` and `BLUE_TIMEOUT`. Then, inside your functions, before starting you will check if the other timeout exists and block it with `clearTimeout()`, here's the code:

```
var RED_TIMEOUT, BLUE_TIMEOUT;

function doajax_red() {
    $("#button_red").attr("disabled", true);
    $('#myplace_red').hide();
    $("#loading_red").show();

    if (BLUE_TIMEOUT!==undefined) clearTimeout(BLUE_TIMEOUT);
    // here ^ you stop the other function

    RED_TIMEOUT = setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test_red.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#buy_out_form-id').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#loading_red").hide();
                $("#button_red").attr("disabled", false);
                $('#myplace_red').show();
                $('#myplace_red').html(data);
            }
        })
    }, 10000);
}

function doajax_blue() {
    $("#button_blue").attr("disabled", true);
    $('#myplace_blue').hide();
    $("#loading_blue").show();

    if (RED_TIMEOUT!==undefined) clearTimeout(RED_TIMEOUT);
    // here ^ you stop the other function

    BLUE_TIMEOUT = setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test_blue.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#buy_out_form-id').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#loading_blue").hide();
                $("#button_blue").attr("disabled", false);
                $('#myplace_blue').show();
                $('#myplace_blue').html(data);
            }
        })
    }, 10000);
}
```